# Android Resource Linking failed: values.xml

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner

[Android resource link failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIQcq.png)

So,I'm Building this scanner app and I encountered this error of android resource linking after building the connection with the firebase database,i tried cleaning and rebuilding [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIQcq.png),even tried changing the versions,but it did not work!
If anyone could help out,it would be great

Comment: This question is too vague. Please detail the error that you encountered. Post what you see in Android Studio's build log.

Comment: I just added the image,please take a look!
Thanks

Comment: please omit the attribute with style "dialogCornerRadius" and try

Comment: Please share your build.gradle file... don't link it, please share it in here.